Issues with Creating Hikari DataSource Using Denodo Driver and Repeated Query Failures
I'm trying to create a Hikari DataSource with the Denodo driver:
@Bean
  DataSource dataSourceDenodo() throws ClassNotFoundException {
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.denodo.vdp.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("denodo.jdbcUrl"));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("denodo.userName"));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("denodo.password"));
    dataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(30);
    dataSource.setPoolName("denodo");
    return dataSource;
  }

I have the denodo-driver.jar file in my project. For some reason, I'm getting the following message:
com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource - Registered driver with driverClassName=com.denodo.vdp.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase - denodo - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (null)
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - denodo - Added connection com.denodo.vdb.jdbcdriver.VDBJDBCConnection@4cad7e97

I'm trying to understand this because when I'm trying to query Denodo, it only works for the first call. If I try to call it a second time with the same query, I get:
Error querying database. Cause: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: denodo - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30241ms.

I tried to put Class.forName("com.denodo.vdp.jdbc.Driver"); in the method, but this didn't help.
I tried different driver versions from Denodo website.

Ok, I think I have this figured out
The problem with the driver not being found seems to be related to the Denodo driver itself (com.denodo.vdp.jdbc.Driver). This driver might not be registered as a JDBC driver. However, HikariCP will load another driver (VDBJDBCDriver) through direct instantiation, and this should work fine.
The issue with only the first query being successful was resolved by setting the following parameter:
dataSource.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
From Hikari docummentation:

connectionTestQuery
If your driver supports JDBC4 we strongly recommend not setting this property. This is for "legacy" drivers that do not support the JDBC4 Connection.isValid() API. This is the query that will be executed just before a connection is given to you from the pool to validate that the connection to the database is still alive. Again, try running the pool without this property, HikariCP will log an error if your driver is not JDBC4 compliant to let you know. Default: none

In sum:

Driver Not Found: The Denodo driver (com.denodo.vdp.jdbc.Driver) might not be registered, but HikariCP will handle it by directly instantiating VDBJDBCDriver.

Query Success Issue: Setting dataSource.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1") ensures that each connection is validated before use, solving the problem of subsequent queries failing.


By adding the connectionTestQuery parameter, HikariCP validates each connection before it is used, ensuring that the connection is still alive and preventing issues related to stale or invalid connections.
